# how to create a oracle job with a sysdate arg?

Tags: oracle

I create a oracle job like this:

```sql
declare
    job_id number;
begin
    sys.dbms_job.submit(job => job_id,
    what => '
    DECLARE
      PD DATE;
    BEGIN 
      PD := TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1);
      XXX.SP_XXX(PD); 
    END;',
    next_date => to_date('2021-09-13 01:20:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
    interval => 'TRUNC(sysdate+1)+(1*60+20)/(24*60)');
    commit;
end;
```

and exec the procedure was fine.

```sql
BEGIN
  XXX.SP_XXX(TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1));
END;
```

when I run the job

```sql
BEGIN
  dbms_job.run(job_id);
END;
```

report "ORA-12011: execution of 1 jobs failed."

oracle version : 11g

What is my query mistake?

Comment: What is the error in the log?

Comment: Just  “ORA-12011: execution of 1 jobs failed.“， I cann't find other err log.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/scheduse008.htm